# Restrict multiple image within div with JS/Jquery/CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On my webpage there are [Gridster](https://dsmorse.github.io/gridster.js/) widgets.In these widgets initially the images are displayed from JSON(the name of image comes from JSON which I then put in `src` of image)

The users can also add images by clicking `+` button.User can  also delete an image by clicking `X` button on the image.

**The Problem I am facing**

When the images coming from JSON are more or when the user manually adds more images then the images go out of widgets.

**My Desired Output**

Now I was trying to restrict those images in widget such that images will lay only in boundaries of div.

When there are more images the other existing images will resize and all of the images will fit in that area.

When I delete an image the other images will get bigger.In any case the entire area will be occupied by the images.

JS:

```
    //JSON which I get from backend
    
    var json = [{
        "html": "https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/802768-200.png,https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/802768-200.png,https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/802768-200.png", //3 Images
        "col": 1,
        "row": 1,
        "size_y": 2,
        "size_x": 2
      }
    ];
    //Loop which runs over JSON to generate <li> elements in HTML
    
    for (var index = 0; index < json.length; index++) {
      var images = json[index].html.split(',');
      var imageOutput = "";
    
      for (var j = 0; j < images.length; j++) {
        imageOutput += '<div class="imagewrap"><img src=' + images[j] + '> <input type="button" class="removediv" value="X" /></div></div>';
      }
    
      gridster.add_widget('<li class="new" ><button class="addmorebrands" style="float: left;">+</button><button class="delete-widget-button" style="float: right;">-</button>' + imageOutput + '<textarea>' + json[index].html + '</textarea></li>', json[index].size_x, json[index].size_y, json[index].col, json[index].row);
    }
    
    //Function to delete an image from widget
    
    $(document).on('click', '.removediv', function() {
      $(this).closest('div.imagewrap').siblings('textarea')
      $(this).closest('div.imagewrap').remove();
    
    });
    
    //Function to delete a widget
    
    $(document).on("click", ".delete-widget-button", function() {
      var gridster = $(".gridster ul").gridster().data('gridster');
      gridster.remove_widget($(this).parent());
    });
    

    
    //Function to add mode Images to widgets from Modal
    
    var parentLI;
    $(document).on("click", ".addmorebrands", function() {
      parentLI = $(this).closest('li');
      $('#exampleModalCenter').modal('show');
      $('#exampleModalCenter img').click(function() {
        $(this).addClass('preselect');
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('preselect');
        selectedImageSRC = $(this).attr('src');
      })
    });
    
    $('#add-image').click(function() {
      parentLI.append('<div class="imagewrap"><img src="' + selectedImageSRC + '"> <input type="button" class="removediv" value="X" /></div>');
      parentLI.children('textarea').append(', ' + selectedImageSRC);
      $('#exampleModalCenter').modal('hide');
    })
```

HTML

```
 <div class="gridster">
      <!--  <li> from JSON are placed here images are a part of li -->
      <ul>

      </ul>
    </div>
```

The [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sz6bmmjn/) so far

I am not sure if this can achieved just with CSS or will require any JS along with that

**Update 1**

I have tried with a lot of different CSS but still not able to get the expected output so if someone can help me with it would be really helpful

Comment: Stop reposting questions.

Comment: Sorry for repost but I was not getting the required way to go with it

Comment: Apologies for that

Comment: And I am not getting to how to handle the dynamic nature because the images are not fixed.If they were fixed there are lot of resources available on SO

Comment: This was one of my try https://jsfiddle.net/40s3v142/3/ But this is not working

Comment: There is something I am missing and I am not able to get that

Comment: @H.B. Can you please help me with that

Comment: No, it's a mess. There's too much code, your question has no paragraph breaks, there is no actual/expected output example.

Comment: Okay I will correct it so that you can understand it

Comment: I have updated the question and also made the code as required as per my understanding.Let me know if anything else is remaining from my side

Comment: @H.B. Is it helping you to get question in a good way now ?

Comment: This is a much better question now. But i do not know the answer, maybe someone else will.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167631/discussion-between-newbie-and-h-b).

Comment: No, let us not.

Comment: Thanks for making it better question though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe Gridster has a built in way to arrange items inside the grid cells, in case you have not found a way yet, try [this](https://jsfiddle.net/ehmoh314/63/).

I added some css:

```
.image-wrap-container{
  min-height: 70%
}

.image-wrap-container div.imagewrap{
  width: 33%
}

.text-area-wrap{
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30%;
    display: inline-flex;
}

.new.gs-w{
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 200px
}

.addmorebrands{
  position: absolute;
  left:0
}
.delete-widget-button{
  position: absolute;
  right:0
}
```

and restructured a little bit your html so images fit good within the cell, I hope that does not break anything, javascript was the least modified, only to add the images according to the new html structure.

Note: I tried to make the `li`s' height adjust to the amount of elements it contains, but `[data-sizey="2"]` kept getting in my way, so before throwing some probably unnecessary hack on it, try and achieve that using the library's own options, good luck.

Also, I noticed you were using this to update your `textarea`s:

```
parentLI.children('.imagenames').val(function(i, selectedImageSRC) {return selectedImageSRC + ', '});
```

which won't work because you are using the same name for the argument, conflicting with the original `selectedImageSRC` variable. In case you are still having problems in that front, I replaced it with:

```
parentLI.children('.imagenames').val(function(i, currentContent) {return currentContent + ',' + selectedImageSRC + ', '});
```

**Bonus Feature**

The buttons for removing an image were to big for the images and covered quite a big part, so I took the liberty:

```
.removediv{
  visibility: hidden
}
.imagewrap:hover .removediv{
  visibility: visible
}
```

hope it helps

Comment: As always Perfect !! :)